# Spring - SFTP authentication intermittently failed

Tags: java, spring, networking, sftp, jsch

It looks the issue so strange. In our prod server, we have been establishing SFTP connection through jsch. It works well till noon of the day with the authkey of the server. All of sudden for 30 mins we experience issue due to auth failure. Then again it started working. Please advise.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:193)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:332)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:350)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Too many bad authentication attempts! 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:987)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:83)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:263)
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we figured out the root cause of the issue. It looks like FileNet team has some threshold to accept invalid credentials. When application exceed this invalid attempts threshold, it throw off `SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Too many bad authentication attempts!` 
and put on hold accept new connection for 15 or 30 mins seems.

It looks like one of the scheduler program in prod uses invalid credential to hit the FileNet by standalone repeatedly. Because of which, other programs which suppose to be working fine got error out intermittently when the Filenet failed to accept new connection due to exceed threshold of bad authentication attempts caused the by other program.